# Center Icon and Text in a button Xamarin XAML

Tags: image, xaml, button, xamarin

I don't how to center the icon inside the button and get it above the text, I didn't find information also about it, I'm asked to do a kind of "tabb" option menu, but below the screen, and I found that it was kind of "hard" because of the "design implications"etc, so I decided that with buttons would be easier, but the problem now is how to center the image and get the text right, If some one could help me, that would be great. This is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         BackgroundColor="Silver"
         x:Class="XamForm.View.MainPage">
<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" />


 <StackLayout Padding="30">
<Label x:Name="lblCuantos" Text="No #" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="20"/>
<Label x:Name="lblNombre" Text="" FontSize="20"/>
<Button  x:Name="btn1" Text="Oprimir" Clicked="Accion"/>
<Button  x:Name="btn2"  BackgroundColor="White" Image="iconRes.png"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Gridd" TextColor="Gray" Clicked="Accion2"/>
<Button  x:Name="btn3"  BackgroundColor="White" Image="iconRes.png"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  TextColor="Gray" Clicked="Accion2"/>


</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the actual result of the button itself:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/11so9le.jpg

This is what the final result of the menu should look like kind off

http://oi62.tinypic.com/10pzw2f.jpg

Thank you!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `ContentLayout="Top,0"` in button. For Example in your case use below code

```
<Button  x:Name="btn2" ContentLayout="Top,0" BackgroundColor="White" Image="iconRes.png"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Gridd" TextColor="Gray" Clicked="Accion2" />
<Button  x:Name="btn3" ContentLayout="Top,0" BackgroundColor="White" Image="iconRes.png"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  TextColor="Gray" Clicked="Accion2"/>
```

Comment: I am try this one but i'm not visible image in android and ios only text only visible

Comment: I tried that on button with larger text, the image swifts on right from center

Answer (score 2):

You could use a StackLayout with Orientation set to Vertical, and in it add Button and Label.

Answer (score 0):

The Button.Image property is of type  FileImageSource so any image that is 'local' can be used in a button. This means the following code will work:

```
someButton.Image = "imageName.png";
```

or you can write

```
someButton.Image = ImageSource.FromFile("imageName.png");
```

if **imageName.png** is located in each of the application projects (Resources folder in iOS, Resources/Drawable folder in Android, and application root in WinPhone; each with the appropriate build action set).

The Xaml equivalent is:

```
<Button Text="Has Image" Image="someImage.png" />
```

See the [Working with Images doc](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) for full details of what the build action should be for each platform.